# How to define scriptmanager timeout property in custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page

I have a custom master page. When you create a custom master page then another page with similar name is automatically created by SharePoint.
For e.g. my master page name was mymaster.html so sharepoint created mymaster.master file with it.
I want to increase the AsyncPostBackTimeout property of ScriptManager. I opened mymaster.html in SPD but didn't find any code there. Then I opened mymaster.master in SPD and I can see the ScriptManager code written as below.

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager" runat="server" --more code here-- />
```

Problem is, SPD doesn't allow you to edit .master page and I can't add this code in my .html master page file. How to edit this code in SPD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### How to customize master pages in SharePoint 2013

> In SharePoint 2013, if the master page, for example, `oslo.master` is
>   associated with a html page, i.e., `oslo.html`, you cannot edit the
>   .master page directly. You should edit the html page with your
>   favorite html editor(for example, Visual Studio), find the right place
>   to insert your  tag. SharePoint will automatically synchronize
>   your change to the .html file to the .master.

For more information follow [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/31c8c028-52ed-43ed-8539-1cb25d892628/basic-footer-for-sharepoint-2013-masterpage?forum=sharepointcustomization)

From another hand, in order to edit master page directly, the association with html page should be broken (SharePoint 2010 mode).

Below is demonstrated how to break the master page association and customize master page file.

### Example

1) Open master page `Olso.master` in Edit mode

2) Select `Save as` action to save it as a custom master page, let's name it, lets say, `helsinki.master` (Note: `helsinki.master` is **not** associated with html page, it means it could be edited directly )

3) Open `helsinki.master` and find `asp:ScriptManager` control

4) And finally, specify properties for `asp:ScriptManager` control and save the changes

Comment: Ok if I edit helsinki.master then how will my .html file know that this is the .master file? Because you said helsinki.master is not associated with any html page hence how will changes made in helsinki.master will take effect on website?

Comment: @FrankMartin since the Master Page has no associated Html File.. You don't need any Html file, just upload the .master file in Master Pages and Page Layouts library, check-in and publish (approve if approval is on) and you should see your Master Page in the drop down

Comment: Oh so you mean to say this will be my new master page which I need to use?

Comment: That's correct and the previous comment is absolutely correct